# 02 upstream wire harness diagram

Tags: p0171, code

I have a 1996 Dodge Neon 2.0 L Vin C. DTC P0171 when I went to change 02 Sensor. I saw that my upstream 02 sensor connector harness side got melted, was to close the the exhaust. Don't know how to find which wire goes where, how do I figure this out. Your help will be so much appreciated. I have a wire diagram, still need help please.

Comment: Can you pull out your cell phone, take a picture of that wiring diagram, put it somewhere public online and edit your post to add the link?  Is that  a heated oxygen gas sensor or not heated?  I thought for that car it was a single wire element.   Additionally photos of your sensor parts would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: I would think its a 4 wire.  Given that it is 4 wire, you have 2 grounds, a heater wire and a signal wire.  You can find a schematic for your car to determine what wire goes where.  Not sure how to tell on the o2 side, unless you can look it up from the manufacturer.